# Does the Victoria Line pass underneath Downing Street?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

Since I've never been to the UK, I can't understand the reason why V said that the Victoria Line is blocked between St. James & Whitehall. I looked up the Victoria Line and found out that it doesn't stop anywhere between St. James & Whitehall:

[image: Map of the Victoria Line, following its real world path].

As I know, the car which contains

> V's corpse

departed from Victoria station and exploded underneath Downing Street. How could this be possible?

Comment: [Plot armor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor) helped V

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi stack exchange! Our community members have tidied up your question, and now it's looking really good and answerable! When you can, please take the [tour] and checkout the [help]

Comment: I am not as well versed with the [tube map](http://www.bbc.co.uk/london/travel/downloads/tube_map.html) as some, but I suspect the answer lies in the fact that the line the tub follows, and the approximated schematic I linked make some compromises. As such, there will be a chunk of the line 'between' those two stations, that won't be obvious from the image you provided

Comment: @Anna - Just to clarify, are you asking about the comic or the movie?

Comment: @LogicDictates - I think we can assume it's the comic since V blew up Big Ben in the opening of the graphic novel, not with a train but with a demolition charge in the clock tower; https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d6xq.png. He then threatened Downing Street. In the movie Downing Street doesn't get a mention. First it's Lady Justice, then the Houses of Parliament.

Comment: Wasn't the whole point of that scene that they were in an old, abandoned section of the tube that's not part of the system anymore (or maybe never was, just being an uncompleted extension)?  Otherwise, how would they have loaded up all those explosives without being noticed?

Answer (score 24):

The remark made by V was:

> the Victoria line is blocked, twixt Whitehall and St. James.

There are two problems with relating this to the Victoria line which we know from our reality. Firstly, as the map shows, the Victoria line does not go to St James or anywhere close (although it does pass almost directly beneath Buckingham Palace). Secondly there is no tube station called "Whitehall". Assuming that Whitehall corresponds to the real-life station of Westminster, the only tube line that does connect these stations is the Circle and District line. This gets to within 200 m of 10 Downing Street (although it does not actually run beneath it).

[image]

So the only solutions I see are either that V misspoke and that the train actually traveled along the Circle and District line. Alternatively, given that *V for Vendetta* takes place in an alternate reality, the Victoria line takes a different trajectory there. Given the mention of "Whitehall station", which does not exist here, this may be the more likely solution.

Following Anna's comment, it is apparent from the map shown in the graphic novel that the line in question corresponds to the Circle and District line in our reality. So maybe in the Vendetta universe it is simply the case that that line is named as the Victoria line (and its route makes a little jink to take it under Downing Street). Out-of-universe, maybe Alan Moore just got the name wrong. Closer inspection of the Vendetta map shows a "Strand" station between Charing Cross and Leicester Square. That's not present in our world any more, so the networks *are* slightly different.

[image: Comparison of the tube map in Vendetta with the current London underground]

Comment: It's possible that the reference to Whitehall was merely alluding to the area in general, and not necessarily to a theoretical Underground station existing there. On a sidenote, is that quoted dialogue actually present in the movie? I'm aware that it's present in online scripts for the movie, but I can't find it in the movie itself, and there seem to be clear deviations between that script and the dialogue in the movie, suggesting that this may have been an early draft which was subsequently revised. I've searched for a direct transcript of the movie, but haven't found one as yet.

Comment: @LogicDictates Even so, the only tube line going through Whitehall is the Circle and District line.

Comment: I don't think the Victoria line takes a different trajectory. Since the tube map from the graphic novel is exactly the same as the one from our real life. Also since Evey also mentioned that victoria line was blocked between st.james and whitehall, it couldn't be possible that these two characters misspoke the word twice. Therefore I guess the author made serious mistake.

Comment: @Anna The line shown in the tube map in the graphic novel is clearly the Circle and District line. So maybe in the Vendetta universe that line is named as the Victoria line (and its route makes a little jink to take it under Downing Street). And on closer inspection, the Vendetta map shown a "Strand" station between Charing Cross and Leicester Square. That's not present in our world, so the networks are slightly different.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez There was a Strand station on the Piccadilly line from 1907 to 1915. Then it was renamed Aldwych, and it closed in 1993.

Comment: @MikeScott Yes, but on the Vendetta map it seems to be on the Northern line (at least as far as I can see).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez The Northern Line part of Charing Cross used to be called "Strand" station (1915 - 1973)

Comment: Is there any way "the old Victoria line" could refer to a different line than the one now called Victoria?

Comment: @FrancisDavey Interesting! But Vendetta was written in 1982 (and is set in 1997), so that Strand station would have been removed from the map long before.

Comment: @Ben there were proposals for a new underground line similar to the route of the Victoria line dating from 1943, but the construction of the actual line started in 1960. AFAIK the name "Victoria line" had never been used for a different line on the network.

Comment: As someone who actually lives in London, I'd like to make a correction. The District Line and the Circle Line, which are two separate tube lines, share a single track for part of their route. Where this occurs, locals in fact call the conjoined service the District and Circle; but it runs alongside the river, along the Embankment, and is never within 600 feet of Downing Street. Not all tube tunnels are shown on modern tube maps: there are a number of abandoned tunnels, associated with routes that have become disused, such as the link line which once connected Aldwych Station to the network.

Comment: Just to explicitly note a) the Charing Cross / Embankment section has been re-jigged quite a lot in the last 40 years and b) there are old bits of line and stations around there (indeed that's what they used for filming).

Comment: Bit of a stretch, but it might make sense if you consider "the Victoria line" as a phrasing of "the line [from here] to Victoria", as opposed to the actual Victoria Line. Whitehall vs Westminster might be poetic license: Whitehall scans better in "'twixt Whitehall and St James"

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not possible using the tunnels as they exist in our universe. The most common maps of the London underground are schematics and not geographically accurate. However the latter [do exist](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=8a567ebac15748d39a747649a2e86cf4) and show the Victoria line running well to the west of Downing Street.

[image: Extract of London underground map]

Comment: Schematics? I prefer to call them topological diagrams :-)

Comment: I still can't get it. The skyblue line is not even close to the whitehall. Are you talking about the gray colored line? Which refers to the jubilee line? But I'm pretty much sure that V's body was loaded on the victoria line.

Comment: Some labels would improve this greatly.

Comment: @Anna The light-blue line is the Victoria line, which indeed does not go very close to 10 Downing Street (marked more-or-less with the black circle on Whitehall). The gray line is the Jubilee line which gets nearer, but still not very close. The green is the District line.

Comment: @Valorum Agree labels would be better - have edited, at the same time demonstrating why I'm not an artist.

Comment: The Victoria Line is twice as far from Downing Street as the Jubilee Line, the latter running between the stations at Westminster and Green Park; but the Jubilee Line is at least as far south of Downing Street as the District and Circle Line is east of it. At their closest, the two lines are each about 1/8th of a mile from Downing Street.

Comment: The grey line is the Jubilee Line Extension, which opened in 1999.  Prior to that the 1977 Jubilee Line terminated at Charing Cross - ie going from Green Park to the north end of Whitehall. The running and platform tunnels still exist and are used for filming occasionally.

Answer (score 8):

In the past, there have been many different routes proposed for new tube lines, and each new line which was proposed came with multiple different proposed routes at different stages before construction began.

It is not difficult to see how a novelist, writing about the tube network in the 1980s, at the time when planning was in progress for the new Jubilee Line, could have been writing at a time when the route, which was fairly uncertain at many stages of the planning, was intended to pass much closer to Downing Street.

The novel is set 15 years after 1982, the date of writing: it is perfectly reasonable to take the view that a writer in 1982 could legitimately have believed, given the uncertainties involved, that a decade and more later the new Jubilee line would lie quite close to Downing Street. He was speculating about a largely unknown future.

The proposed route which would have routed the new line from Westminster tube station to the existing station at Picadilly Circus, instead of to the neighbouring station at Green Park to which it now runs, would have in fact taken the Jubilee Line beneath Downing Street.

One point I can definitely clear up. The use of the name 'Victoria Line'. Many of the initial proposals were to build the new line, today called the Jubilee Line, as a simple extension of the Victoria Line. It was originally going to be much shorter: it grew in the planning, until eventually it became a completely new line: but in 1979 it started out as a short extension to the existing Victoria Line. It was a long way down the road in the construction phase before the belated decision was taken to name it the Jubilee Line.

Comment: Moore wasn’t a novelist, and the Jubilee line was named in 1977, in honour of the Queen’s Silver Jubilee. And before that, it was called the Fleet line. And the part of the line from Green Park to

Comment: @MikeScott "*Moore wasn’t a novelist*"  Moore describes his works as "comic books", but the rest of the world tends to call *V for Vendetta* a "graphic novel".

Comment: @Graham But it was a monthly serial, not something published as a single complete work.

Comment: @MikeScott So were most of Dickens' works, but we'd still call him a novelist.

Comment: The Fleet/Jubilee line was _never_ an extension, short, or otherwise, of the Victoria line. In 1979 it was built from Baker Street to Charing Cross, taking over the Stanmore branch of the Bakerloo, and was extended into East London in stages to 1999.

Comment: I remember the disruption caused in the early 1980s by the construction work; and as the building progressed I definitely recall one of the new sections which eventually got linked together and called the Jubilee was initially a Victoria Line extension. I think they began work at various different places, and some tunnels were linked to the network and in use while others were still only partially complete. Some bits of the new service definitely began as new sections of the existing Victoria and Bakerloo lines.